# How to show people voicing their opinions in essays

Tags: quotes

In my essay, I'd like to show a group of people in a stadium crticizing a football team.  I want to use direct quotes to show what different people in the group are saying but I am not sure how to put this in an essay so that it is correct.

Is the proper format something like:

> I heard complaints all around the stadium.
>
> "I could have played better than that!"
> "This was the worst 90 minutes of my life."
> "I hate football!"

Or am I completely mistaken?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about literary/narrative style, and should be asked on [writers.SE](http://writers.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ok.you can use a colon instead of a period after the word "stadium." Each quote as a separate paragraph is good.